# Get referring site IP address in PHP

Tags: php

I want to implement a referral program for my SaaS product.

The partner will have a link on their website that will direct their user to my signup form:

```
domain.com/referral/201030
```

"201030" being the member id from the partner site.

I want to make sure the page request came from my partner site,

I know I could check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but that is not secure.

Is there a way I can check the IP address of the site referring the user to my webpage with PHP?

Comment: http is stateless, so no

Comment: Since you are in control of the link generation, you can add some information to make this secure.  The originating site can implement a shared secret used to hash the parameters (including a timestamp), and on the receiving end you can do the same hash to see if they match.  If it did, you have verified the origin.  By including the timestamp, you limit the effectiveness of replay attacks.  See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Comment: i cant imagine most partner sites wanting this kind of  hassle, they just want a simple link - my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**When do you need high security?**

For an API for example, you want to track the incoming traffic and make sure only authenticated clients can access the API. This needs higher security standards and exchange of  public keys and secrets.

**When not?**

A referral program doesn't need this kind of security.

The more traffic you have, the better for you. You don't care where the [**lead**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_generation) is coming from. When I send my partner program link to someone via messenger, there is not even a HTTP_REFERER.

**Is it even possible?**

It is <strike>very difficult</strike> impossible to make sure where the user is coming from without serverside interaction, obfuscation and dynamic links.

**Any chance?**

The only way, using a static link, is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. You can downvote the answer now, but it doesn't change the fact that there is no way, with a simple, non-dynamic link like shown in the question.

**Turn the referer into an IP**

To turn the HTTP_REFERER into an IP:

```
$urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$ip       = gethostbyname($urlParts['host']);
```

Keep in mind, this is not reliable nor secure in any way.

Comment: what API? your the one confusing things

Comment: @Dagon I am not, young padawan. Can you show me an example of a webpage, where high security is involved for a partner referral program?

Comment: Although your post is very helpful, it's not really an answer to his question. He want's to know if he can get the IP address from a referring link. The answer is, no. The follow-up is "you don't actually want to do that".

Comment: @Dagon I did not say the OP mentioned API?!